# What language is the CLR written in?

Tags: languages, clr

Just out of curiosity, what language is the CLR written in? I read on the Java Virtual Machine wikipedia entry that it is programmed in C++; is this the same for the CLR?

Sorry if this is off-topic, I didn't feel that this question was technical enough to go on Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Could be Java! Okay, maybe not...

Actually, the CLR is written mostly in C++ and a little garnish of assembly language according to this: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/netfxbcl/thread/e7ca66a9-aac5-47b7-b41f-01b1f1543f38/

C++ is a good language for this since it is at once portable, fast, and expressive.

You didn't ask, but FYI, the Framework Class Library (FCL) is C#. Makes sense too - a good dog fooding exercise.